# How to Ignore Spring boot configuration in the dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy

I am working on test framework application, which is built in groovy, java 8 and springboot framework.  Recently, one of the dependencies was upgraded to its latest version.

When I run the tests, the test fails with below message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: class path resource

    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:229)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57)
    ... 92 more
```

I see this error coming from the autoconfiguration in spring.factories of one of dependency:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration= 
com.app.api.config.testAutoConfig

I am guessing this issue is occurring because the dependency is built in Java17 and I am compiling my test framework in Java 8.

How can I ignore the autoconfiguration in the dependency.  Is there a hack or what is the correct way of implementing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

No need to hack, there is an API! :)

[`SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#exclude())`|`[`EnableAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfiguration.html#exclude())`#exclude()`.

Just like:

```
@SpringbootApplication(exclude = com.app.api.config.testAutoConfig.class) // type safe alternative : Class[]
class MyApp // ...
```

For *exclusion*, the "non-type-safe"/string alternative makes sense:

```
@SpringbootApplication(excludeName = "com.app.api.config.testAutoConfig") // ... String[]
```

[**`#excludeName`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#excludeName())

...  which brings the advantage, to (possibly!?) exclude it from your class path (completely;)

Comment: but this is more regarding "How to Ignore Spring boot configuration in the dependency", regarding your specific probem: not sure! 1.: whether this can prevent it from class loading 2. If you can't use the configuration, why do you think/how you can use any of its classes?

Comment: This AutoConfig is from another transitive dependency. My application is not using it. So, it is something like this. MyApplication--DependentJar--Its DependentJar which is having this autoconfiguration.

Comment: ok, @SajitGangadharan, `exclude` helps?

Comment: no, Now the exclude throws same exception when starting the application stating it cannot identify the class because of unsupported major version

Comment: 1. Tried also `excludeName` ? 2. what happens, if you remove the dependency?